# Copy innerText of HTML element to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML anchor element and I'd like to copy *only* the innerText of that element to the clipboard. All the methods I try seem to copy the innerText and the anchor itself, so just pasting what has been copied shows the text as a link. So it seems to be copying the outerHtml for the element. I know I can paste as plain text, but I just want to copy the text. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve hacky solutions like hidden inputs?

I've tried using both Range.selectNode and Range.selectNodeContents, but both of these seem to behave the same way, and include the anchor in what is copied to the clipboard.

Here's a fiddle illustrating this: https://jsfiddle.net/zjoraen1/

```
function copyMe {
    getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.querySelectorAll("a")[0]);
    getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

I expect to paste plain text, but see text formatted as an HTML anchor.

Comment: It is working fine in the fiddle without copying the tags

Comment: What OS and editor are you using for the paste? If I paste it into Notes on Mac, it looks and behaves like a link.

Comment: Windows 10, visual studio code

Comment: You'd probably need to be pasting it into something like WordPad to see it as a link.

Comment: Nop. Still text

Comment: I just tried on Windows too pasting into Microsoft Word and I get a link there too, so not sure what's different between our environments.

Comment: well, i copied from the fiddle. did't try to run in my system

Comment: It's copying only the text here too (Windows 10, Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98).

Answer (score 0):

I also can't get it to work even when selecting the text node with `document.querySelector('a').childNodes[0]`, range seems to want to copy as a link.

I would suggest using a function which can copy any text string, your current code won't work on a number of devices anyway e.g. [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/45308151#45308151)

And just passing the string to that on click - `copyToClipboard(document.querySelector('a').innerText)`